# How to use autoincrement for a SELECT INTO of a GROUP BY result in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by, select-into

I found this

```
SET @row_number = 0; 
SELECT 
    (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, 
    firstName, 
    lastName
FROM
    employees
ORDER BY firstName, lastName
```

solution [here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/) for adding row numbers to a MySQL result, but it doesn't work for a `GROUP BY`-result, as the row number is not continuous, but "jumps" by the amount of rows that are grouped.
Or is there a specific solution for `SELECT INTO`, if there is already an auto increment column?

Comment: Not with you , if there is an auto_increment column you need do nothing..

Comment: @P.Salmon How do I use this with a `SELECT INTO`?

Comment: Please add the table definition for the table you are selecting into together with sample data and expected outcome.

Comment: Also I am having a hard time understanding why and what you want to group by.

Comment: @P.Salmon It's a general question. How do I have a continuous count while using a `GROUP BY`-clause statement?

Answer (score 0):

It is basically the same, you nee dfirst to GROUP By and then Makes the row_number

```
SET @row_number = 0; 
SELECT 
    (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, firstName, lastName
FROM
    (SELECT 
        firstName, lastName
    FROM
        employees
    GROUP BY firstName , lastName) t1
ORDER BY firstName , lastName
```

With MySQL8.x this gets a lot easier.

I am not really sure what you mean by SELECT INTO

But i think you mean an outfile, as you have4 multiple values

```
SET @row_number = 0; 
SELECT 
(@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, firstName, lastName
    INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
 FROM
    (SELECT 
        firstName, lastName
    FROM
        employees
    GROUP BY firstName , lastName) t1
ORDER BY firstName , lastName
```

If you want the selected data insert into another table thsi would look like

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT 
(@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, firstName, lastName
    INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
 FROM
    (SELECT 
        firstName, lastName
    FROM
        employees
    GROUP BY firstName , lastName) t1 , (SELECT @row_number = 0) t2
ORDER BY firstName , lastName
```

Comment: You forgot the `INSERT`-part...

Comment: Selet Into what? SELECT INTO only works in loops and when you have silge rows. Which you don't have, so what exactly you want to send to ttable into Ort do you mean a Outfile?

Comment: I need to select from one table into another, but just distinct data.

Comment: the inner select select uniwue Name combinations each row is distinct guaranteed by the group by. Soi don't get what you are asking for and why the SELCT INTO idf you want to enter it into another table, non of which you mention in your question, so tka e4 the selct and use it as would you any other